# Java Generics: How to create a to-n collection with configurable value holder type

Tags: java, generics, collections

My goal is to create a 1-to-n container class based on Java collections. (Roughly something like a `Map<String,Collection<Double>>` -- for a single string the map can hold n doubles. For example, for a key "coordinate" the container can hold the values [3.1, 4.3, 7.2]).

A required feature is that it shall be possible to freely define the type holding the n elements per key. So the Collection in the above example should be replaceable by a List or a Set.

The following must be possible, and if it is, the goal is reached:

```
OneToN2<String, Double, List<Double>> cl = 
    new OneToN2<>( ArrayList.class );
OneToN2<String, Double, Set<Double>> cs = 
    new OneToN2<>( HashSet.class );
```

Now I started with the following code:

```
package com.fun.with.generics;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * A map that maps a single key to n values.
 *
 * @param <K> The key type.
 * @param <V> The value type.
 * @param <V> The type used as container for the to-n elements.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OneToN2<K,V,CT extends Collection<V> > extends HashMap<K, Collection<V>>
{
    private final Constructor<CT> _containerCtor;

    /**
     * Create an instance.
     */
    public OneToN2( Class<CT> claß )
    {
        try
        {
            _containerCtor = claß.getConstructor();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Need default ctor." );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a single key value pair.
     *
     * @param key The key.
     * @param element The element to add.
     */
    synchronized public void add( K key, V element )
    {
        Collection<V> ct = get( key );

        if ( ct == null )
        {
            ct = makeToN();
            put( key, ct );
        }

        ct.add( element );
    }

    /**
     * Add an element for multiple keys.
     *
     * @param keys The keys to add.
     * @param element The element the keys refer to.
     */
    synchronized public void add( Collection<K> keys, V element )
    {
        for ( K c : keys )
            add( c, element );
    }

    /**
     * Get a newly allocated container holding the n values.
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<V> get( Object key )
    {
        Collection<V> n =
                super.get( key );
        Collection<V> result =
                makeToN();

        result.addAll( n );

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the to-n container.
     */
    private Collection<V> makeToN()
    {
        try
        {
            return _containerCtor.newInstance();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            throw new InternalError( "Could not create to-n collection." );
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I kept only a minimum set of operation demonstrating my intentions.

So far so good:  I was able to technically express my intention and the compiler accepted it, so success in the first step.

Now to the problem:  I am not able to create an instance of the above type :)

The following example use cases show the intended usage but neither of them is working:

The intended solution would be:

```
// Declaration (this compiles):
 OneToN2<String, Double, List<Double>> x;
// Initialisation (does not compile). Error is Type mismatch: cannot 
// convert from OneToN2<String,Double,ArrayList> 
// to OneToN2<String,Double,List<Double>>
 x = new One2N2<>( ArrayList.class );
```

Bummer, but I understand that the compiler cannot infer that the ArrayList.class is-a List. So I tried the less-ideal but acceptable alternative:

```
// Declaration (this compiles):
 OneToN2<String, Double, ArrayList<Double>> x;
// Initialisation (does not compile). Error is Type mismatch: cannot 
// convert from OneToN2<String,Double,ArrayList> 
// to OneToN2<String,Double,ArrayList<Double>>
 x = new One2N2<>( ArrayList.class );
```

Again bummer, with a more or less constant error message.

**The question is: Where do I go wrong?**

(Why do I want that? Academic interest, fun with Generics. But honest, I created similar types in several systems resulting in code duplication because the to-n container is fixed. To prevent this, I'm looking for a generic implementation.)

Comment: Have you considered using Guava multimaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Java 8 then a `Supplier` will clean things up for you.

```
public class OneToN2<K,V, CT extends Collection<V> > extends HashMap<K, Collection<V>>
{
    private final Supplier<CT> _containerCtor;

    /**
     * Create an instance.
     */
    public OneToN2( Supplier<CT> _containerCtor )
    {
        this._containerCtor = _containerCtor;
    }
```

...

```
    /**
     * Create a new instance of the to-n container.
     */
    private Collection<V> makeToN()
    {
        return _containerCtor.get();
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate your collection like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OneToN2<String, Double, List<Double>> x = new OneToN2<>(ArrayList::new);
}
```

Comment: Almost literally the same answer, at the same time :)

Comment: I saw :). You removed it? I thought yours was better. Feel free to edit if you have anything to add.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `CT` type parameter. Instead of providing a `Class` in the constructor, provide a factory used to create the inner collection (through interface, or in Java 8 you can provide just the method).

```
public interface CollectionFactory<V> {
    Collection<V> createCollection();

public class OneToN2<K,V> implements Map<K, Collection<V>> {
    public OneToN2(CollectionFactory<V> factory) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Also, I recommend you *use* `HashMap` instead of *subclassing* it (i.e. prefer composition over inheritance).

Comment: +1 to composition over inheritance; but I wouldn't say to get rid of `CT` - you can use it in `HashMap<K, Collection<V>> -> HashMap<K, CT>`, and make the get method return `CT` instead of `Collection<V>` (which is fine because of covariance).

Comment: @AndyTurner Are we in agreement that the solution is to use a factory instead of providing the collection class in constructor (to avoid the trouble with `class` object for parameterized class)? I guess removal of `CT` is rather opinion- / context-based (depends on whether the type of collection is part of type info semantically in your context).

Comment: Composition over inheritance.  I fully understand the concept and decided deliberately for inheritance, since the implementations provided by the HashMap implementation fits my needs. But this is a secondary point.

Comment: Getting rid of CT is a cool key point. Basically I actually need just a factory for my container type, which is nicely expressed by the CollectionFactory.

Comment: (Uh, no paragraphs.)  The less cool aspect of the CollectionFactory is that it gets a bit wordy if I create an instance when inlining the CollectionFactory definition.

Comment: Yes, it's quite verbose in Java 7 and lower. In Java 8, you can use lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Well this compiles fine in my IDE:

```
OneToN2<String, Double, List<Double>> x = new OneToN2(ArrayList.class);
```

Got rid of the `<>` in `new OneToN2`

Also this link might prove useful: [Passing a class with type parameter as type parameter for generic method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471701/passing-a-class-with-type-parameter-as-type-parameter-for-generic-method-in-java)

Comment: I think this will result in a warning: unchecked assignment. But as the declared type is well typed it could work, though I'm not comfortable with the removal of <>. Why use them anyway if it makes no difference in the end? (I'm really questioning me and I'm curious of the answer)

Comment: The good thing is that this trick solves the compile error.  But introduces instead a warning. Actually removing <> makes a difference. The <> request the compiler to infer the types from the definition and when doing so it concludes that the types are incompatible. Leaving the <> out switches more or less to a compiler compatibility mode introduced to support existing code that predates Generics.