# Checked cast of parametrized generic abstract class to it's implementation

Tags: java, generics

I have a complex method that returns different implementations of `DiffResult<T, V>`. I would like to do a checked cast to the implementation in order to call it's methods and assert the result.

```
// this is ok
DiffResult<MockVersion, String> result = calculator.diff(a, b);

// this is problem
NewCurrentVersionDiffResult<MockVersion, String> newCurrentVersionDiffResult = assertDiffType(result, NewCurrentVersionDiffResult.class);

// this is ok
Assert.assertEquals("expected", newCurrentVersionDiffResult.getNewValue());
```

the `NewCurrentVersionDiffResult` has the following header

```
public class NewCurrentVersionDiffResult<T extends ProductDataVersion<T>, V> extends DiffResult<T, V>
{ /* ... */ }
```

I have tried this

```
private static <D extends DiffResult<T, V>, T extends ProductDataVersion<T>, V> D assertDiffType(final DiffResult<T, V> result, final Class<D> type)
{
    Assert.assertThat(result, CoreMatchers.instanceOf(type));
    return type.cast(result);
}
```

this works when executed, but reports compilation warnings

```
[WARNING] VersionDiffCalculatorTest.java:[34,102] unchecked method invocation: method assertDiffType in class VersionDiffCalculatorTest is applied to given types
  required: DiffResult<T,V>,java.lang.Class<D>
  found: DiffResult<VersionDiffCalculatorTest.MockVersion,java.lang.String>,java.lang.Class<NewCurrentVersionDiffResult>
[WARNING] VersionDiffCalculatorTest.java:[34,102] unchecked conversion
  required: NewCurrentVersionDiffResult<VersionDiffCalculatorTest.MockVersion,java.lang.String>
  found:    NewCurrentVersionDiffResult
```

I would like have it working and without the warnings.

I know about `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, I'm using it myself on other places. But this case is obviously broken, because when I tell IDEA to declare local variable from `assertDiffType(result, NewCurrentVersionDiffResult.class)` it generates

```
NewCurrentVersionDiffResult newCurrentVersionDiffResult =
```

and not

```
NewCurrentVersionDiffResult<MockVersion, String> newCurrentVersionDiffResult =
```

Also the warning is on the invocation of the `assertDiffType()` method, not on the method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `NewCurrentVersionDiffResult.class` to the method for the `Class<D>` parameter, which is how it determines the type of `D`, which is also the return type. Note the lack of generic parameters on `NewCurrentVersionDiffResult` there. That's why the method returns a raw type.

Unfortunately, you can't just do `NewCurrentVersionDiffResult<MockVersion, String>.class`. The question of how to handle this [is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18471823/2643425); long story short, you should use [`TypeToken`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken) from the [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <D extends DiffResult<T, V>, T extends ProductDataVersion<T>, V> D assertDiffType(final DiffResult<T, V> result, final TypeToken<D> type) {
    Assert.assertThat(result, CoreMatchers.instanceOf(type.getRawType()));
    return (D) result;
}
```

With this, you can do:

```
NewCurrentVersionDiffResult<MockVersion, String> newCurrentVersionDiffResult = assertDiffType(result,
        new TypeToken<NewCurrentVersionDiffResult<MockVersion, String>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to use the required type but you can suppress the warning with this @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  , in few case we can't do much we have to use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") if not possible

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a solution for the problem, I've updated the question.